# Why are my variables different depending on whether they're an array or an integer?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables, methods

Reading around the internet about Javascript arrays and their methods I found something and I don't understand what is happening.  I was specifically reading about the Array.reverse() method:

```
var numbers = [60, 50, 20, 30];
var value = numbers.reverse();

console.log(numbers); // [30, 20, 50, 60]
console.log(value); // [30, 20, 50, 60]
```

What confused me about this was why was the value of the variable "numbers" changed here?

I'm confused because the same would not hold true here:

```
var number = 3;
var value = number * 2;

console.log(number); // 3
console.log(value); // 6
```

I realize in the first example I'm dealing with arrays, and in the second just integers.  I don't understand why the value of the variable "number" IS modified when you perform a function on the variable "value".  However it isn't modified in the second example.  What is the difference here?

Comment: `reverse()` mutates the array

Comment: The key here is that reverse, per specs, operates in place and returns a reference to the source array. While I feel that's an unfortunate design choice, the root of this is that you have two variables that reference one array object.

Answer (score 4):

[`Array.prototype.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) reverses the array in place, i.e. it modifies the original array in the process.

From MDN:

> The `reverse()` method reverses an array *in place*. The first array
>   element becomes the last, and the last array element becomes the
>   first.
>
> ```
> var a = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
> a.reverse(); 
>
> console.log(a); // ['three', 'two', 'one']
> ```

---

In the second case, you are doing a simple calculation with [primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Primitive_values). This does not change the primitives used in the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

> What confused me about this was why was the value of the variable
>   "numbers" changed here?

Because the variable `numbers` is a reference to an array in memory, and when `reverse` is called it modifies this array.

While here you are working with primitives

```
var number = 3;
var value = number * 2;
```

and primitives are immutable in JS

Comment: thanks @Maximus , this in combination with the answer from Timo.  It all makes sense now. Thank You.

Comment: @Fabian, no problem, you can upvote if you found it helpful :)